# Python OOP class method Book

Tags: python, class, object, methods

`Book.No_Pages() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'Words' and 'Font_size'`
the error comes in line 14
The code is:-

```
class Book():

    def __init__ (b1,Font_size=12,Words=300):
        b1.Words = Words
        pass
        b1.Font_size = Font_size
        pass

    def No_Pages(b1,Words,Font_size):
        return b1.Words/b1.Font_size
cyn_Book = Book(300,12)
print(cyn_Book.Font_size)
print(cyn_Book.Words)
print(cyn_Book.No_Pages())
```

I actually tried this by another approach like adding pass after the `Font_size` and `Words` and thought that it could return `words 300`,`Font_size 12` and `pages` being `15`

Answer (score 0):

So `No_pages` isn't using those parameters (`Words` and `Font_size`) - it's getting them from the `b1` parameter (which would conventionally be called `self`, btw.) Essentially you're handing it an entire container, `b1`, and it's getting everything it needs from there - but you've also told it it should be explicitly handed `Words` and `Font_size`, which it doesn't need. Because you're not passing them, it's failing.

You can fix this by changing the `def No_Pages(b1,Words,Font_size):` to `def No_Pages(b1):`

By the way, what did you think `pass` would do? That doesn't actually do anything, it's just used as a placeholder if you have a block of code you haven't written yet (and need to have something there.) For instance, you might do:

```
if some_condition:
    pass
```

because you haven't worked out the statements you need yet, but omitting the pass statement would make python fail because it expects *something* to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referring to the instance using `b1`, you need to add the `self` argument to class methods, for the sake of convention. For eg., your `__init__` would then become

```
 def __init__(self, Font_size=12, Words=300):
        self.Words = Words
        self.Font_size = Font_size
```

Moreover, your `NoPages` function takes 3 parameters and you're providing only one, that is `b1`. Hence the error `Book.No_Pages() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'Words' and 'Font_size'`

You may rewrite it as

```
 def No_Pages(self):
        return self.Words/self.Font_size
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your class definition to:

```
class Book:

    def __init__ (self, font_size=12, words=300):
        self.font_size = font_size
        self.words = words

    def no_pages(self):
        return self.words / self.font_size
```

When you define a function like `no_pages` you say what arguments it expects.  If you define it like this:

```
    def No_Pages(b1,Words,Font_size):
```

then it expects three arguments: `b1` (the object itself, which is provided automatically when you invoke an instance method, and usually referred to as `self`), `Words`, and `Font_size`.  Since the function expects the `Words` and `Font_size` arguments, it will raise an error if you call it without them.  You don't need those arguments to be part of this function at all, though, since `self` already contains them.

Adding `pass` doesn't do anything; you only use the `pass` keyword in cases where a block of code is expected (e.g. in the body of an `except`) but you don't actually want to execute anything.

You can simplify your class further if you use `@dataclass`, which builds the constructor for you based on the class's attributes:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Book:
    font_size: int = 12
    words: int = 300

    def no_pages(self):
        return self.words / self.font_size
```